# Appium | Getting error when using .click or sendkeys

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, appium, mobile, mobile-automation

I'm looking to start automation of a mobile application. I went through Appium related articles and most of them suggest to use Appium with Javascript. I explored online and setup appium and my code thus far looks like:

```
var wd = require('wd');
//var app = require('sample-apps');


var remotes = {

local: {

    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 4723
}


}

var environment = remotes.local;

    desiredCaps = {


        deviceName: '4d86aed1',
        platformVersion: '5.1.1',
        platformName: 'Android',
        appPackage: 'delhivery.lastmile.dev',
        appActivity: 'delhivery.feapp.heavy.ui.LoginActivity'
        //app: 'http://appium.s3.amazonaws.com/ContactManager.apk'
    },
    driver = wd.remote(environment);
    driver.init(desiredCaps)



    //driver.elementById('etPhoneAL').click()

    driver.quit();
```

The code gets executed and I can view logs in the appium server session.
As soon as I uncomment "driver.elementById('etPhoneAL').click()" the script fails instantaneously and no appium logs whatsoever!

Command to trigger script: "node simple-appium-android.js "
And the error received:

```
/home/orgaone/Mobile-Appium/android/simple-appium-android.js:33
    driver.elementById('etPhoneAL').click()
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/delhivery/Mobile-Appium/android/simple-appium-android.js:33:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
```

I'm new with both Appium and Javascript so any suggestions how I can build a mobile testing framework (things like suggested practices, what framework to use etc.) using the aforementioned would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that `driver.elementById('etPhoneAL')` returns NULL. So there is a problem in code in getting element and you should change your code to identify the element and then you can click on it.